# Cant knit chunks with process macro by Hayes

Tags: knitr

Hello i am using the Process Macro name process.R by Hayes (4.1.1). It cant knit all the process chunks like this one

```
process(data = daten, y = "OCB", x = "NAR", m = "SK", model = 4)
```

I also put this knit option at the beginning of my code, because of all this process chunks, it didnt want to knit any of the code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
```

I have this error notification in the knitted output file:

```
## Error in process(data = daten, y = "OCB", x = "NAR", m = "SK", model = 4): konnte Funktion "process" nicht finden
```

However, this code does work and it printed out result. Only knitting doesnt work.

I appreciate your time for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already figured it out, but you need to insert the macro with `source("process.R")` prior to the first usage of the function. Otherwise this function is unknown resulting in the error message you mentioned.